I need help switching sprites when I press A and D
I am trying to make a script where the sprite changes depending on what button you press, right now I am only doing A and D, left and right. I cant get anything to work, I have tried everything I can,
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using UnityEngine;

public class Sprites
{
    public string gameObject;
    public SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;
    public Sprite SpriteRight;
    public Sprite SpriteLeft;

    void ChangeSprite()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))
        {
            gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = SpriteRight;
        }
    }

}

I have tried many forums and different approaches, and nothing ever ends up working, im new to unity as well.

Are you calling ChangeSprite() in the GameObject's FixedUpdate() or Update() ?

When I call it into Update() it still gives me the error, and a warning

what error? what warning?

The error I got was, Assets\SpriteChanger.cs(20,28): error CS1061: 'string' does not contain a definition for 'GetComponent' and no accessible extension method 'GetComponent' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
And I cleared the warning and cant get it to come back

public string gameObject; you defined gameObject as a string.

It wouldn't work any other way, what would I have to do?

I got it to work now, thank you for messaging!

As Piko Miko found in their comment, you have a public string gameObject; which shadows the MonoBehaviour.gameObject variable, so your later gameObject.GetComponent call was trying to run GetComponent on a string.
If this behaviour is attached to the GameObject you're trying to modify the sprite for, you can just remove the string gameObject, so the code will call GetComponent on the actual gameObject variable.
Alternatively, you could just use the spriteRenderer variable you also created directly, assuming it's assigned in the inspector:
spriteRenderer.sprite = SpriteRight;

